# Is it Real tears or Liquid?

Tags: character, terminator-series, the-sarah-connor-chronicles

In *Terminator: The Sarah Connor Chronicles* season 2 episode 4 Cameron temporarily loses her memory as a machine, and discovers  distant memories of the resistance fighter. She came to act like a human. After she talks to the consultant in the house Cameron was crying. When she's crying tears come from her eyes. My question is, when Cameron was crying, are the tears coming to her real human **TEARS** or some kind of synthetic liquid?

[image]

Comment: You mean was Summer Glau actually crying..then Yes.. As to whether Terminator have internal fluids to *simulate* eye-hydration...probably.

Comment: i'm talkinh here about Terminator Robot not the real actress.. i know real Summer Glau actually crying.

Comment: Tears are some type of liquid...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Was the *Terminator* crying?

## **Yes**

> If mission requires, a T-900 can lie like a T-850 does. Further more, since a T-900 features unsurpassed human mimicry, making it able to fake emotion, such as crying, to cheat enemy/target in order to achieve mission or avoid being terminated.
>
> Note the tear ducts are necessary for eye lubrication and protection, so it is logical to assume all living-tissue-covered Infiltrators features them, otherwise their eye tissues would quickly degrade to the point where it would be obvious they are not human. Of course, that does not imply they are all programmed with the ability to cry as the T-800 told John Connor, *"I know now why you cry, but it is something I can never do."*, which strongly suggests that earlier models do not have the necessary connections and/or software for their emotions (or their equivalent) to trigger crying.

[**Terminator Wiki**](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/T-900_(The_Sarah_Connor_Chronicles))